# Custom AlertView controller is not showing top of view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

am new to swift i have two view controllers in first view controller had button when click that button it will push to second view controller.there also i have addclick button when i click that button i have pop to first view controller when i pop to first view controller i am showing the alert view and popupview but both are not showing i trying so many way i am not find any thing

```
first view controller 
inside button 

   let lv = NAViewPresenter().otpViewController()
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true)

second view controller button


 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  self.addAlertViewAction()

 func addAlertViewAction() {
           let alertController = UIAlertController(title:NAString().add_my_service(), message:NAString().addButtonloadViewMessage(), preferredStyle: .alert)
            // Create OK button
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                let lv = NAViewPresenter().addMySerivesVC()
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true)
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
```

how to show alert view after popview controller

Comment: share the button action of second view controllar

Comment: if (lbl_OTPDescription.text == NAString().enter_verification_code(first: "your cook", second: "their")) {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            self.addAlertViewAction()
}

Comment: pls edit it in your question, can't imaging from comment

Answer (score 1):

When you popup the VC is deallocated , so replace this

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

with

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Display Xib Popup View also 
popupView = PopupView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 300, height: 120))
        popupView.center.x = view.view.bounds.width/2
        popupView.center.y = view.view.bounds.height/2
        popupView.lbl_Message.text = NAString().addButtonloadViewMessage()
        self.popupViewTitle()
        popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        popupView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.view.addSubview(popupView)

Comment: Alert View is Working.

Comment: Before alert View PopupView display.

Comment: Please elaborate , what do you mean by these comments does this fixes the problem ?? Is there another one ??

Comment: Your **PopupView** is a **UIView** differs from **alertController** which is  **UIViewController**